# sed inplace replacement replaces itself

Tags: shell, sed, sh, ksh

I have a single file shell script (BusyBox, no bash, ksh I believe) that I want to write a path to itself when run. I need #home to be replaced by home=/home. I have this:

```
var="/home"
#home
sed -i 's/#home/home=$var/g' /this/file.sh
```

When run it'll replace #home and the string in the sed line and the $var is not expanded:

```
var="/home"
home=$var
sed -i 's/home=$var/home=$var/g' /this/file.sh
```

This is my desired outcome:

```
var="/home"
home=/home
sed -i 's/#home/home=$var/g' /this/file.sh
```

I'm pulling my hair getting this to work. Any hints?

Answering myself this works as expected:

```
var="/home"
#home
sed -i "s|^#home|home=${var}/|g" m.sh
```

Comment: try `sed -i "s/#home/home=$var/g" /this/file.sh`

Comment: see [sed substituting with shell variables](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/sed/1096/substitution/3519/substitution-using-shell-variables#t=201608300833232824835) for further reading

Comment: sed -i 's/^#home$/home=$var/g'

Comment: clearly, the question is not related to shell variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there may be several ways to address this question. Try adding the circumflex (^) at the beginning of the pattern to indicate that this pattern should be found at the beginning of the line.

Before running the script (here it is named m.sh)

```
#!/bin/bash

var="/home"
#home
sed -i 's/^#home/home=$var/g' m.sh
```

After running the script

```
#!/bin/bash

var="/home"
home=$var
sed -i 's/^#home/home=$var/g' m.sh
```

**EDIT** 
You may also want to consider removing the `g` modifier in sed since you only want to match once in the line.

Comment: Oops! Looks like user pdg commented on this while I was typing the answer.

Comment: Works, but I need home=$var to be expanded to home=/home

Comment: Using pipes as a separator and putting var into braces works. Thanks for the help.

Comment: But since var is already set and home points to var, isn't it unnecessary?

Comment: $var is not a set variable, it is only used as an example here. It's the outcome of some querying code.

Comment: Thanks for the g modifier suggestion.